# Adjust ROC analysis for multiple testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, roc, adjustment

we did an exploratory prospective study in medicine in order to find parameters which are able to predict a specific post-surgical event (0/1) before the actual surgery. We have about 10 parameters evaluated and did a ROC analysis which provided pretty decent prediction with one of the parameters (AUC = 0.854, p < 0.001).
My question is, since we tested about 10 parameters, does is make sense to adjust for multiple testing and if yes, what method would you propose?

Thanks a lot!
Striatum

Comment: How did you test an AUROC curve?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you fit a model with 10 parameters and are wondering if you need to adjust the p-value?

Answer (score 1):

The context of ROC curves doesn't seem to matter IMO. You have a set of p-values obtained by performing multiple hypothesis tests - that's it. You could use p-value correction methods such [Bonferroni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) or use a [false-discovery rate (FDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate).

Comment: I second that(+1). On top: with 10 tests and p <.001 you are not running into any problem with that.